# Where is the CSRF vulnerability in this Python CGI application?

Tags: csrf, python

I have the following Python code, and I am wondering which line is most likely to expose a CSRF vulnerability.

```
import cgi
import Cookie
c = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
email = form.getvalue("EmailAddress")
c['addr'] = email
```

Comment: Are you asking us to do your homework?

Comment: I would be glad to talk about CSRF all day long.  You might consider re-submitting this question about CSRF rather than asking to solve a particular problem.

Comment: I would jokingly answer line1, because if it wasnt a web based form it couldn't be vulnerable to csrf.

Comment: That, or line 6, because here the form value "EmailAddress" is directly written into a cookie without sanatizing it first.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt CSRF is not about sanitizing input fields. You need to go back and reread the OWASP guide.

Comment: Line 6. That's because you are setting the value email to attribute 'addr' without having a Token generation. That's  a easy catch

Answer (score 3):

## What the code does

Lets look at what the code does.

```
import cgi
import Cookie
```

First we just need to import some libraries to be used later.

```
c = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
```

This stores all the cookies sent in the clients request in the variable `c`.

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
```

This stores all the form values sent in the clients request in the variable `form`.

```
email = form.getvalue("EmailAddress")
c['addr'] = email
```

Then the value of the form field with the name `EmailAddress` is stored in the variable `email`, that in turn is used to set the value of the cookie `addr`. Presumably this new cookie value will later be sent back to the client as a part of the response, and stored there.

## How the attack works

So how could an attacker use this in a CSRF attack? Lets say an evil attacker creates a website called `http://evil.com` that she somehow convinces the victim to visit. The evil website contains a hidden form that is automatically posted to the site with the vulnerable script (lets call it `http://example.com`) with JavaScript. The form contains a hidden input with the name `EmailAdress` and the value `hacker@evil.com`.

Now the attacker has changed the victims `addr` cookie on `http://example.com`, so when the victim later visits that site it will believe her email adress is the attackers. If that email adress is used by the site to send some sensitive information, like a password reset link, the attacker will get that information.

## But what line?

I think asking for the specific line introducing a vulnerability is a bit odd. It is not a single line that causes a vulnerability, but a series of circumstances. I would rather argue that it is the absense of many lines, namely lines containing some CSRF mitigation like a token check, that causes the vulnerability.

But if you have to pick a number as answer to your homework, I think the above discussion should help you finding the right answer.

Comment: Brilliant way to help out with homework! Wish I could +1 more than once